# How close are we to full immersion/deep dive Virtual Reality ?(as in percentage)

Tags: technology

Will it happen within our lifetimes?

By using nervegear, nanobots, mind uploading, Neuralink maybe?

And if we get full dive VR will it be limited to gaming?

Or it is just all fantasy?

Comment: Hi and welcome to worldbuilding! Which is kinda what we're here for. Coming up with ideas and solving problems for *fictional* worlds among other things. I don't really know off the top of my head which stack exchange this would fall under. *Possibly* biology? If you were to rework this into a question on "How might my world with deep dive VR have got there from today?" it would be more on-topic. Of course, you'd want to do more work on the question itself as well. If you need help you can ask around. I believe there's a chat you can jump into...

Comment: I see you already asked this exact question over on GameDev.SE, and it was closed there as well. For future reference, if a question of yours is closed as off-topic, please do not bounce from Stack site to Stack site looking for a place where it *is* on-topic. Only re-ask it somewhere else if you are redirected there by other users. (FWIW, I don't think this would be on-topic on Biology.SE; it's a tech question more than biology.)

Comment: @F1Krazy yeah there just doesn't seem to be a stack site for this question though. I went through the [list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) and it'd be a hard sell at any of the engineering sites and entirely out-of-scope at any computing ones. Biology atleast might deign to answer the biology-related portion.... do we send stuff like this to Quora? >_>

Comment: So I do expect this question to be closed.  WorldBuilding tries to answer one question at a time, and you seem to be focusing on several aspects of VR at once.  However, I do think that if you take to heart the critiques and questions raised in the 2 answers provided so far, you should be able to hone this question down to one which is answerable on this site!

Comment: FWIW, we have 100% certainty in 2 things, this is a singularity science & it's possible given current knowledge. We have uncertainty on many things: final form of VR, needed development to hit tech explosion, what conscious even is (let alone if it's movable), and if future science advancements will close doors. (like new science closed the door of FTL, it was a dream, *maybe* possible but now impossible). TL;DR if it's possible within your lifetime you'll see an singular advancement or rate of advancement that'll signal you. Unless there's a deadwall. (Fusion hit such a deadwall)

Comment: The question has four major issues that need to be solved to fit in: it asks multiple questions at once, what has been asked is not answerable, there is no wb context established and there is no sign of research. I'm sorry, the question itself is comparable to many other questions here, I can see why one would ask it here (I suggested in the meta before that relaxing the rules might lead to confusion). Sadly this site is a q&a that helps people build fictional worlds and not a place to discuss the challenges of mankind. You will find plenty of  other online communities where this is on topic

Comment: I will add that if this question is actually about worldbuilding, there are plenty of examples of it being used to greater or lesser extent, like Ready Player One, The Matrix, etc. So you could just pick a level of technology you want and build your world around it. If this is just to try to predict real world results, then Cort and TCAT are correct; there is no way to predict this. It's not outside the realm of possibility at least.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we know how close we are.  I don't think we can measure such things.

One of the challenges is defining what "dive" VR means.  Consider the haptic systems demoed on [Smarter Every Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK2y4Z5IkZ0).  This glove made for an "immersive" experience, but that's because the bar is so low.  The line for what qualifies as "immersive" moves with the technology, and it's hard to be some percentage away from a moving target.

The one answer I am certain of: if we get full dive VR, I am 100% certain beyond any shadow of a doubt that it will not be limited to gaming.  There is not a single technology since the beginning of time which has found itself limited to gaming.  There's no reason such a powerful technology would be the first.

The real question is whether or not nerve stimulation is a reality.  What's funny about this is the big problem is the awesome *messiness* of our nervous system.  It has great precise detail in the aspects it cares about the most, but other things are just sort of squashed together.  Nobody has yet found a reliable way to map which nerve fibers in the spinal column come from which parts of the body.

An interesting question would be whether we could grow children with connections to a VR world in their mind.  While our computers are currently too calous and coarse to dovetail with the human mind, the human mind is very good at forming connections with things.  We may see people grow up with VR capability.

As for mind uploading, that's more opinion based, but my personal opinion is that the concept of mind uploading fails to properly jive with how we perceive the mind.  As such, no matter how good the technology is, we'll feel it falls short of "mind uploading."

Comment: I definitely agree with VR not staying confined to gaming. I've got my boss pretty close to sold on the idea of buying me a VR setup as soon as the resolution gets good enough to read fine text. Why? Virtual work spaces. I have a lot of different duties, and even with a 49" 4K monitor and two 24" monitors, things can get kind of cluttered. In VR there is no such thing as maximum window size. And windows could be clustered by task. Over here is the cluster of desktop programming windows. Over there are my web dev windows, etc. And I could work in a mountain meadow, or on the moon.

Answer (score 1):

**Tech Development Predictions Are Not Reliable**

In 1949 tech publications breathlessly predicted the incredible announcement that some day in the future computers might only need 1,000 vacuum tubes and weigh only 1.5 tons instead of requiring 18,000 and weighing 30 tons. Unbeknownst to them, transistors which had just been invented two years prior would render the entire concept of using vacuum tubes for computing obsolete and firmly cement their prediction as one of the least accurate in the last century. Whenever somebody is trying to sell you a prediction of the future of technology they are usually just telling you what they wish to be true.

The problem with technological development is that there are often times black-swan events. Utterly unpredictable developments that suddenly and profoundly alter the direction, application, and ideas of a field. We tend to think of solutions to problems in terms of methods we are already trying, only to discover a far better methods we hadn't thought of yet. A good example was a 1920's prediction that people of the future would carry around telephone receivers that they could plug into public telephone jacks to make calls on the go, it was even predicted that at any moment of the day you could call a library to answer whatever question you might have at the moment. The idea of mobile internet and cellular phones accomplishes this task, but is nothing like the methods that people in the last century would have thought up to solve the issue of mobile access to communication and information. In their mind possessing the ability to make mobile phone calls and access information on the go was only a few years away, when in fact it took nearly a century to accomplish.

**Summary**

Predictions of the future tend to be mixtures of people's personal hopes and dreams for the future explained with vague examples involving improved versions of current development. The truth is it is impossible to say what we will be able to do with what we haven't invented yet. When you attempt to get predictions for current tech in relation to full immersion VR you will recieve 3 answers:

**Optimism:** Any day now, possibly within a few years

**Skepticism:** A few decades, maybe.

**Cynicism:** Within the Next Century, if ever.

For reference, the optimists have been promising fully immersive VR entertainment was only a year or two away since I was a child in the late 80's. The only correct answer is that nobody really knows yet.